# Create recursive layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm creating an application that receives a dynamic and recursive data structure, ie, an element can have an identical element within it, something similar to the HTML´s DOM.

At this stage I have "simple" elements type *text*, *date*, *buttons*, and others likes: grid, tables and sections. These last ones, can have a elements inside is structure, something like childrens, for example, a grid element can have other grid.

[image]

These models elements are already being built on a framework through my JSON received, usign a Factory pattern. In that order, i have already a list of elements to be drawn in the view.

My first approach was to implement a UICollectionView, but now i am having trouble drawing elements belongings to others.
Any idea what the best approach to solve this problem? always taking into account the performance of the app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer is likely "autolayout" since it's point is to solve for a constrained layout. But what do you mean by "having trouble drawing elements belongings to others?" What trouble?

Comment: My first approach was to create a UICollectionView, this works fine for simple elements like section, date, buttons... But, when you need to draw, for example a grid, which can have children inside i cant do make it with a simple UICollectionViewCell, since i will never know which type of structure a grid can have inside..

Comment: Right; that's where autolayout would come in. Build a big scroll view. Add constraints, and let autolayout do the work.

Comment: let me summarize to see if I understand: you suggestion is to forget the UICollectionView and create a UIScrollView where I add "one on one" the different elements? with that, i will not loose performance since I am not reuse cells?

Comment: It depends on how you implement each of them as to how it impacts performance. If this is a huge layout, then doing autolayout for the whole thing could be very slow, but you'll have to then build a solution by hand to solve that. This is a big, complicated problem in the general case. There is no "do this and it'll all just work easily." It depends on your exact situation. There's no way to advise you in the abstract.

Comment: My concern is that since I do not have control over the data structure  provided by the server, I'm afraid that could delays the creation of the view, that's why I opted for UICollectionView initially instead of the UIScrollView. Do you know of any examples or hints to make something like this? BTW, thanks for your help

Comment: It could certainly delay things, even with a UICollectionView if the layout is complicated. You will need to build some kind of custom "grid view" in any case (which will probably need its own controller. I wish I had some simple answer. This is a complicated problem and will likely take some effort to develop a good, performant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware of auto layout in such complex layouts. Auto layout has a cost, and the more views and more complex the scene is, the more toll it takes. Adding and removing constraints is costly, and layout passes themselves are costly.

Looks to me a rather simple layout where a collection view is placed inside a table view. Main view seems like a table view (can be a collection but is simple for that). Each element is a cell. Since you tell the table view the cell size, you can have whatever you want inside as long as you can calculate the size. In fact, the section element to me looks like the same table as the main table. Grid element is a collection view. You could do it as a grid view, and then you can use more reuse.

So let's take a look. Simple elements first, text element, date element, title section and footer section are either simple table view cells or collection view cells. Table element looks like a collection view to me but can be anything custom. A grid is a collection view with a flow layout. If you implement everything with collections, you can reuse the same classes for text and date elements as the ones in the main view, otherwise you use collection view cells here. Section element is a cell with a table view. The cell can act as a data source of the table view, or there can be a "nested table controller" which the cell can use as data source of the table view. To get the height of the section element cell, you can get the table view's content size's height and return that. If we further consider, the main view is basically a top level section element table. If you pick the "nested table controller" root, your main view controller can have that as a datasource of the main table view.

To track elements in the section nested view controller (or cell-as-data-source model), I recommend having an array of data representing, and an enum to determine the type. This way you can design the various types and select the cell identifiers based on the enum.

A crude object representation of this backing data structure would look like this:

```
{
    type: Section
    items: {
        {
            type: Text
            items: {}
        },
        {
            type: Date
            items: {}
        },
        {
            type: Grid
            items: {
                {
                    type: Text
                    items: {}
                },
                {
                    type: Date
                    items: {}
                },
                {
                    type: Text
                    items: {}
                },
                {
                    type: Text
                    items: {}
                },
                {
                    type: Date
                    items: {}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            type: Section
            items: {
                {
                    type: Title
                    items: {}
                },
                {
                    type: Text
                    items: {}
                },
                {
                    type: Grid
                    items: {
                        {
                            type: Text
                            items: {}
                        },
                        {
                            type: Text
                            items: {}
                        },
                        {
                            type: Text
                            items: {}
                        }
                    }
                }
                {
                    type: Text
                    items: {}
                },
                {
                    type: Footer
                    items: {}
                },
            }
        },
        {
            type: Table
            items: {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you the same example as your above example scheme.

Parsing this is very simple. At the top, you can either always assume there is a section element, or, even better, just iterate the top level items and use each item's type and in `cellForRow:` return an identifier according to the type, and if a complex type, pass the array of sub-items to the cell, who would perform the same logic and so on.

I used a table view for the vertical flow because they are easier to manager. You can use a collection view with a vertical flow layout as well.

Using iOS7's table view `estimatedRowHeight`, you could even not parse everything but only the most immediate cells for optimization, and create more and more as the user scrolls.

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your answer Leo!!! I like your approach of using a TableView as as the rootController. However I have some questions about your proposal. You advise to create a UITableViewCell subclass that has a Tableview on its contentView, but i didn't understand how to: "The cell can act as a data source of the table view, or there can be a 'nested table controller' which the cell can use as data source of the table view"?; and how can i update the "main table" if a cell in a sub-table is selected for example?

Comment: Well, if a cell contains a table view as a subview, then something needs to be the data source. It makes sense to have that something be the cell itself, or a separate data controller (not view controller) which the cell can own (as well as the table view controller for the main table).

Comment: For selecting, you can travel upwards. If a cell hears that a cell was selected, it can either perform the action or pass it upward the owner chain until there is no one to pass to. So a section element selection will pass to main table which will handle. Or, depending on action, you can handle in the section cell itself.

Comment: makes sense, it was what I was thinking to implement for the cell interaction.

Comment: one aspect that is putting me questions, since to know contentSize a tableView it need to be created, how do I know this value before it is created? I need previously define the height of a cell which in this case will be the size of sub-table, but how do I know it´s height at this stage since it is not defined/created yet?

Comment: @DaSilva There are several solutions for this. You can either use estimated size to fake it (for iOS7 and above) or implement a dynamic loading mechanism, where you only have 5 cells, and as you scroll, you load more and more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Leo Nata!! i didn t understand the "implement a dynamic loading mechanism"?? I am using the estimated size to give a possible and estimated size for the row. After that i need to provide the exact size that the cell (the cell with the table) will have ("heightForRowAtIndexPath"), but the cell/table only will be created on the "cellForRowAtIndexPath"?

Comment: @DaSilva You should provide a mechanism that when accessed, loads more chunks. For example, an autoloading "array", which first preloads 1->20, and then when you access item 17 or 18, it loads more (20 -> 30). Then you will be able to access the item in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` as well.

Comment: sorry @Leo Natan, not figure yet... i need to create a table where the size of frame is the same size of its full contentSize, with that i can create the cell with that full size. Where can i force a table to calculate is full size? thanks

Comment: just one more tip @Leo Natan.. I am with troubles with the custom cells, basically a create a custom  UITableCell for the "simple" elements, however i will like to use these cell too inside the collectionViews,otherwise it need duplicate cells for each simple element. My thought was to create only UICollectionViews, where a table is a "UICollectionView with only one column", whoever i lost the "estimatedRowHeight" of the table (performance issues). Any tip about this?

Comment: @DaSilva Yep, collections miss that. They are harder to maintain. Here is my suggestion, regarding your two questions. Do it like this: Load X items. When table/collection asks you, you tell it you have only X items. Now as the user scrolls and reaches X - (smallDelta), you load X more items, and tell the table/collection that X more items were added (so now there are 2*X itmes). When user scrolls to (2*X - (smallDelta)), you load X more. And so on. This way you can do it with collections only.

Comment: but with this approach how a cell(with a tableview inside) warning the main table to update its height? How can i force to load X items?? thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: The cell does not need to warn the table. The table hears what cell will be displayed (with `willDisplayCellAtIndexPath:`) You can monitor here and load some more. Tables have the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method, which will make them grow in content size as they need.

Comment: sorry to be annoying but I still missing something, how i know the correct size that the cell(with a table inside) will occupy in the method "heightForRowAtIndex"?

Comment: I think there is a substantial lack of understanding of how table views work on your part, which is beyond the scope of this question. You should read the documentation on when each delegate method is called and what data is needed at which point. You do not need to know sizes before the cells are loaded. Once the cells are loaded, you know the sizes. What is the problem?

Comment: i have a cell with a UITableview inside, this cell´s size frame should be the same as the "contentSize of is UITableview# (which is dynamic).

Comment: Hmm... Is there a way you could calculate size without actually creating the cell objects? If you have a small subset of "simple" objects, you could just calculate size by recursive calcHeight method which only calcs height according to item types.

Comment: Let's say text cell is always 44 height, date cell is always 44 height, so you could traverse the data structure quickly just for the heights. You can then cache these heights and use when available, otherwise load more heights and load more cells.

Comment: i already have a method for accomplish that, but since the cells will have a dynamic size, according their text, i cant make some simple calculation like "nr of elements*44".my solution was to implement a method like "returnHeight" for all the "simple objects", where i calculate the estimated size. My only concern is if the cell will have a big number of elements an cause some kind slowness.

Comment: No, you should use a recursive calculation, so you traverse all the dynamic cell possibilities. And you don't have to traverse everything. If you really want to work hard, you could implement a `calculateUntilReachingHeight:` and find out this way how many dynamic cells to load. This is hard, not sure you really need something like this.

Comment: i don t figure your idea. I am using a recursive calculation to the "child" of the cell like:   `int cont =0;
    for (int i = 0; i<[self.childrens count]; i++) { SBFElement * child = [self.childrens objectAtIndex:i];
cont += (int)[child returnHeighCellForWidth:widthScrean];  cont +=5; //margin  } return cont;`

Comment: @DaSilva This may help you also: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/05/scrollviews-inside-scrollviews/

Comment: Nice share @Leo Natan Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure about your questions but sticking to your 'how can I create dynamic layout supporting recursion', I'd advise the following

- Create a UIView subclass
- Give it a model property (e.g. @property GridModel model) or give it an initialiser method with model (e.g `initWithModel:(GridModel *)model`)
- In either `drawRect` method or initialiser methods, make it draw its subviews based on the model
- In your code, parse the json and according to the type of object, initialise this special subview and make it draw
- To draw many subviews dynamically and recursively, keep track of your y offset and make sure next subview starts from where the previous subview ends

Does this make sense?

Comment: to see if you understand,you advise me to create a UIView subclass for each type of element i have, and depending on the list of elements i receive iterate over thats UIViews subclass, and keep adding these to a main ScrollView? My concern with that option is the performance of the app if the list keep increasing.

Comment: Yes that's what I'd recommend. No, performance wise, it should be fine. You can re-use nib's if you're concerned about performance but should be fine.